# Bounty fails for Non-sense question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Why doesn't this question about [Supernova remnants](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35528/particular-detail-about-supernovae-remnant) get a helpful answer even though the bounty is awarded..? Don't anyone like this? or Is it that due to "The question is silly and waste of time"..?

Comment: Why do you not like the existing answer? Reading the question it was not 100 % clear to me either what you want to know. If you are interested in the possible final state of such a collision, you should mention this more explicitely in the title and the body of the question. In this case, I would think the question is interesting ... If you'd like to have more details in an answer you can kindly ask people to write a bit more if they have time, it often works ;-)

Comment: Hello Dilaton: You see, I've a little problem regarding **English**. I'm quite bad. So, I'll keep on revising it until it gets clear..!

Comment: Should we generally try to help you with the English or with editing the questions if it can only be guessed what you want to know? You can always roll back any edits you dont like ... BTW I like the yellow smiley on your picture ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's always the risk that nobody will provide a helpful answer when you set a bounty. After all, it's only an extra incentive to answer, not a requirement.

In this case, I'm just seeing your question now but I'm not really sure what you're asking. It's quite possible that other people declined to answer for the same reason, i.e. because they thought your question was unclear.

Comment: Hello David, Like I told Dilaton, I've a little problem with English. So, I'll keep on revising till it gets clear

Comment: @CrazyBuddy ah, I didn't know that. We try not to punish people for having less-than-perfect English, but there's not much we can do unless we understand basically what you're trying to ask. Something that might help is that when you post a question, if you're not sure whether you phrased it well, post in the chat room and ask for someone to help you proofread it. Even if nobody is in chat at the time, someone will see the message within a few hours and hopefully reply. (I try to check in to chat every day)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it was downvoted without the comments, though it is indeed a bit unclear. I personally know nothing about the problem and I just skipped it.

It has an answer, twice upvoted. A possible reason why it doesn't have another is because other people thought it is already answered, since you haven't provide any feedback to state your dissatisfaction with it.

You should counteract with answerers more to improve and clarify things. As a bonus, editing question and answer will pop the question to the top, showing your efforts, attracting attention of other people. That doubles the effect of the bounty.

Comment: I asked him to explain it somewhat clearly or provide a link... But, there wasn't any response. So, I deleted the comment..!

Comment: You should have left it.

Comment: @Yrogirg Have you looked at the edit history for the bountied question. The explanation for downvotes can sometimes be found therein and that question has an extensive one. Ideally, of course, people will come back and rescind the votes if the question has been fixed, but we don't live in an ideal world.

Comment: @dmckee wow, the original version was better, than the one I saw first!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer this because it's a whole field--- the main thing you are missing is gravitational wave emission--- this has simulation data for the two black hole case now.

There are papers going back decades, it is very active now in astrophysics, and you need someone who is familiar enough with the literature to make comprehensive accurate summary. Sometimes you get lucky, sometimes you don't. I have a vague idea of this stuff, but personally I wouldn't feel comfortable pontificating on it-- I need to know where all the folklore results come from and their limitations and confidence intervals. The question is just too ambitious, and it would probably get an answer if separated into smaller questions separately for neutron stars, black holes, and neutron star and black hole.

I doubt that two neutron stars would be able to merge without making a black hole, since they are close to the limit, but this is just a feeling.